# Sodu: command not working

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

```
~$ sodu bash
sodu: command not found
~$ apt-get install sodu
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Like the answer states, the command is `sudo`; unless you *really* want something else. We cannot know for sure what you really want, `sudo` is our best guess. We cannot know because you haven't revealed what your desired command is supposed to do. If it's supposed to run `bash` (or whatever) as root, then it's `sudo`.

Answer (score 5):

The command is `sudo`, not `sodu`.